# Python Beautifulsoup: finding an element after a specific string

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, find

I have the following html code:

```
<div class="xyOfqd">
<div class="aAAD">
   <div class="Bgbcca">Updated</div>
   <span class="hthtb">
      <div>
         <span class="hthtb">September 30, 2018</span>
      </div>
   </span>
</div>
<div class="aAAD">
   <div class="Bgbcca">Text1</div>
   <span class="hthtb">
      <div><span class="hthtb">Text2</span></div>
   </span>
</div>
<div 
   class="aAAD">
   <div class="Bgbcca">MyText</div>
   <span class="hthtb">
      <div> 
         <span class="hthtb">Text3</span>
      </div>
   </span>
</div>
<div class="aAAD">
   <div class="Bgbcca">Text4</div>
   <span class="hthtb">
      <div><span 
         class="hthtb">Text5</span></div>
   </span>
</div>
<div class="aAAD">
   <div 
      class="Bgbcca">Text6</div>
   <span class="hthtb">
      <div><span 
         class="hthtb">Text7</span></div>
   </span>
</div>
<div class="aAAD">
<div 
   class="Bgbcca">
   Text8/div>
   <span class="hthtb">
      <div>
         <span class="hthtb">
            <div>Text9</div>
            <div><a href="https://google.com">Text10</a></div>
         </span>
      </div>
   </span>
</div>
<div class="aAAD">
   <div 
      class="Bgbcca">Text11</div>
   <span class="hthtb">
      <div><span class="hthtb">Text12</span></div>
   </span>
</div>
```

How can I find `Text3` which is located right after the `div` element with the string of `MyText`?

Comment: How did you try? Show your code. Do you need bs4 solution only?

Comment: I am trying to use bs.find_all(), but I don't know what to pass as an argument to the function. I prefer to use bs4, but if there is another simple solution that would be fine too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`lxml.html`](https://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html) solution:

```
from lxml import html

source = """
<div class="xyOfqd">
<div class="aAAD">
   <div class="Bgbcca">Updated</div>
   ...
   <span class="hthtb">
      <div><span class="hthtb">Text12</span></div>
   </span>
</div>"""

tree = html.fromstring(source)
print(tree.xpath('//div[.="MyText"]/following-sibling::span/div/span/text()'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Only if your structure is the final one, you can have the right value doing this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bfs

 html = """<div class="xyOfqd">
   <div class="aAAD">
    <div class="Bgbcca">Updated</div>
      <span class="hthtb">
      <div>
         <span class="hthtb">September 30, 2018</span>
      </div>
   </span>
</div>
<div class="aAAD">
   <div class="Bgbcca">Text1</div>
   <span class="hthtb">
      <div><span class="hthtb">Text2</span></div>
   </span>
</div>
<div 
   class="aAAD">
   <div class="Bgbcca">MyText</div>
   <span class="hthtb">
      <div> 
         <span class="hthtb">Text3</span>
      </div>
   </span>
</div>
<div class="aAAD">
   <div class="Bgbcca">Text4</div>
   <span class="hthtb">
      <div><span 
         class="hthtb">Text5</span></div>
   </span>
</div>
<div class="aAAD">
   <div 
      class="Bgbcca">Text6</div>
   <span class="hthtb">
      <div><span 
         class="hthtb">Text7</span></div>
   </span>
</div>
<div class="aAAD">
<div 
   class="Bgbcca">
   Text8/div>
   <span class="hthtb">
      <div>
         <span class="hthtb">
            <div>Text9</div>
            <div><a href="https://google.com">Text10</a></div>
         </span>
      </div>
   </span>
</div>
<div class="aAAD">
   <div 
      class="Bgbcca">Text11</div>
   <span class="hthtb">
      <div><span class="hthtb">Text12</span></div>
   </span>
</div>"""


soup = bfs(html, 'html.parser')

result = ''

for div0 in soup.find_all('div',{'class':'aAAD'}):
    for div1 in div0.find_all('div', {'class':'Bgbcca'}):
        if div1.get_text() == 'MyText':
            span = div0.find('span',{'class':'hthtb'})
            if span:
                span_to_return = span.find('span',{'class':'hthtb'})
                if span_to_return:
                    result = span_to_return.get_text()

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build a custom query function to pass into `find()`:

```
def has_my_text(tag):
    found = tag.select_one('.Bgbcca')
    # important to assign the result to avoid calling
    # .get_text() on a NoneType, resulting in an error.
    if found:
        return found.get_text() == "MyText"

soup = bs4.... # assign your soup object
found = soup.find(has_my_text)

# <div class="Bgbcca">MyText</div>
#  <span class="hthtb">
#   <div>
#    <span class="hthtb">Text3</span>
#   </div>
#  </span>
# </div>

# Note your span class is nested so we go two level in
result = found.select_one('.hthtb').select_one('.hthtb').get_text()

# 'Text3'

# This below also works if your other span are always empty texts
result = found.select_one('.hthtb').get_text().strip()
```

Note, the `find()` and `select_one` assume we only need the first match found.  If you need to handle multiple matches, you'll need to use `find_all()` and `select()` and make changes to your code accordingly.

If you want to handle variable texts, you can define your function like this:

```
def has_my_text(tag, text):
    found = tag.select_one('.Bgbcca')
    if found:
        return found.get_text() == text
```

And wrap the function in your `find()` like this:

```
txt = "MyText"
soup.find(lambda tag: has_my_text(tag, txt))
```